# I could prove that Copenhagen QM and causality are incompatible; is it right?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, causality, determinism

A quantum system consists of some states. It is in all of the states but beCAUSE of the act of the measurement, the wavefunction collapses into one state. I am really confused because I can repeat the same measurement and get different results at each time! The probability to get a specific outcome is considered to be a function of the wavefunction, but this is not what I mean. This is OK, but when it comes to predicting the outcome of each measurement, it becomes acausal in my opinion, but I am not sure. I have tried to bring my confusion from my mind to stack exchange and this is the result:
If performing exactly similar observations yields to different outcomes, so it means that the cause of each outcome (=observation) is not enough to determine the outcome. So, what else contributes in determining the outcome to be what it is after each measurement? There is no other cause (that we don't know) because if there was any, it would be that hidden variable that realists like Einstein believed to exist and we are assuming the orthodox interpretation here.Therefore, the only other thing that can contribute in determining the outcome is the system itself. For instance, the electron decides to which state to go! This means that the rest of this causality must be filled by the system itself, so the system must change itself. This is impossible because of the same reason that I cannot pull myself up the ground by pulling my hair upward! (or in mechanics, the third law of Newton explains why something can't change itself by exerting a net force on itself!).

MY QUESTION: So, here is my question: I assumed causality and orthodox viewpoint and arrived at either 1- rejecting orthodox by accepting realism or 2- accepting that systems can cause themselves to be changed. None is logical as the first is in contradiction to my assumption and second is in contrast with the third law of Newton. So, the two assumptions I made are incompatible, that is, they cannot coexist. So, the Copenhagen interpretation and causality cannot be both true, and so the orthodox viewpoint is acausal.
Now, is this argument true? If no, why and if yes, which one do you accept to be true: the causality or the Copenhagen interpretation of QM?

Comment: Exposing your confusion is not exactly the same thing as asking a question. Could you clarify (with more accurate technical terms) what *exactly* you are asking for here? QM is confusing all right, and this is why we have to be precise. For example in your previous question you mentioned a 'causality conjecture', but this turned out to be your own way to frame the problem, since causality is not seen as a conjecture anywhere else that I am aware of. We need common ground to exchange, so please stick to accepted terminology and also make explicit your underlying assumptions.

Comment: True. By the way, I didn't make the name causality conjecture, but I saw it somewhere (in an e book which can't remember). Afterall, you are right. I agree with you about the necessity of putting a precise objective platform for discussion. I would explicitly ask the question by editing it.

Comment: Edited to include assumption and question explicitly!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your question:

If a quantum system is not controlled by local hidden variables, then the outcome of a measurement is random. This "random" outcome must be "chosen" by the system and I find this weird and paradoxical. Is their a nice fix?

My answer to this:

You basic idea that every effect must be fully determined in a deterministic way from its causes is a common idea that most physics kind of like, but no one has found a (pleasing) way of making it fit with the results of quantum experiments, which (so far as anyone can tell), actually do respond to certain measurements at random. Experiments such as Bell tests [1] show that this randomness cannot be simply explained by some kind of variable that we cannot see.

So I would re-evaluate your assumptions. Why is a system randomly "deciding" to be spin up and not spin down at random so unsatisfying? Either that or you could adopt the many-worlds point of view. (The rough idea of this is that the system never randomly decided, it remained both spin-up and spin-down. Their are now two copies of me, one sees spin-up, the other spin-down.)

Your idea that "the system caused itself to be changed" is maybe over-stating it. It changed in response to a measurement, so you could say that it was interaction with the measurement instrument that changed the system, rather than it changing itself.

Roughly, what Bell inequalities (and quantum experiments in general) tell us is that our basic intuitions and assumptions about how reality work are completely wrong. It is not possible to explain these things without introducing something into our world-view that seems "insane". Which kind of madness you want you will have to choose:

- Many Worlds (deterministic but multiple copies of you)
- Copenhagen (doesn't really say anything, but is random)
- Qbism (I don't get this one) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Bayesianism
- Paralel lives (believing this one makes you a weirdo (even amongst quantum philosophers), just so you know) - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.10016.pdf
- Pilot Wave theory

Have an awesome day in every branch of the universal wavefunction.

[1] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem

Comment: Great answer, and thank you so much for that. I still can't find my answer, but if you answer the following question, I would probably find it: if Copenhagen interpretation is assumed, and an electron spins up and not down, then what makes the electron to spin up but not down? I think according to the Copenhagen interpretation, the answer is nothing! This is not satisfying because the electron spin up and not down, while it could spin down and not up. There must be a cause for this choice that Copenhagen interpretation ignores.

Comment: And here is my question: did you see any fallacy through reading the previous comment! In other words, do you agree with my reasoning that the Copenhagen interpretation does not hold causality as it lets electrons to decide for themselves?

Comment: @seyedsepehrmousavi: " There must be a cause for this choice that Copenhagen interpretation ignores." - This is the point that is controversial. The current state of human knowledge is that their is NOT a cause for the choice. I agree with you it is weird (and so does basically everyone), but this is the current limit of human knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I think the implications section of the delayed choice quantum eraser article would be a good place to start:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser

If memory serves, IF causality is violated by the Copenhagen interpretation, it's in a meaningless way because no useful information can be transferred through that kind of mechanism.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will read the article.